# Flutter does not work anymore after upgrading

Tags: flutter, dart

My project was working perfectly and Just today i have upgrade my `Flutter` then everything start going run.

At the bottom is the error they give me.
Please help me.

```
file:///Users/macbook/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/animated_background-1.0.4/lib/image_helper.dart:17:30: Error: The argument type 'dynamic Function(ImageInfo, bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageStreamListener'.
 - 'ImageInfo' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('file:///Users/macbook/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
 - 'ImageStreamListener' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('file:///Users/macbook/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'ImageStreamListener'.
    newStream.removeListener(listener);
                             ^
file:///Users/macbook/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/animated_background-1.0.4/lib/image_helper.dart:20:25: Error: The argument type 'dynamic Function(ImageInfo, bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageStreamListener'.
 - 'ImageInfo' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('file:///Users/macbook/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
 - 'ImageStreamListener' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('file:///Users/macbook/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'ImageStreamListener'.
  newStream.addListener(listener);
                        ^
file:///Users/macbook/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/animated_background-1.0.4/lib/image_helper.dart:21:41: Error: The argument type 'dynamic Function(ImageInfo, bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageStreamListener'.
 - 'ImageInfo' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('file:///Users/macbook/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
 - 'ImageStreamListener' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('file:///Users/macbook/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'ImageStreamListener'.
  return () => newStream.removeListener(listener);
                                        ^
Compiler failed on /Users/macbook/AndroidStudioProjects/alimmentation/lib/main.dart
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you tried flutter clean? Maybe that'll work? Also perhaps post the output of flutter doctor and flutter run -v.... Also make sure you have the latest flutter SDK  and check out this thread just came across it https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24645

Comment: Here is my flutter doctor

`flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.6.3, on Mac OS X 10.14.4 18E226, locale fr-BF)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.34.0)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!`

Comment: Perhaps post it in the question next time but good to know there are no issues

Comment: @JoeA Thanks For sure new time I'll do it. Is there any solution?

Comment: Why do you not just fix the code? It clearly says what the problem is and upgrading the framework can introduce breaking changes.

Comment: The only solution I can think is as I mentioned: (1) Make sure you have the latest flutter sdk, (2) try flutter clean  or (3) It could be an AndroidX compatibility issue found here https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility, (4) update the code I would recommend that

Comment: im pretty sure the error is saying that the parameter list of the `listener` function is wrong. the parameters need to match that of the typedef `ImageStreamListener`

Comment: see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flutter-announce/NWTszrEq9U0 - it was done in [v1.6.2](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Changelog#v162)

Comment: Try upgrading the photo_view package in pubspec.yaml to latest version, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

Solved a similar issue by replacing

```
/*...*/.addListener((ImageInfo image, bool synchronousCall) { /*...*/ });
```

with

```
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';

/*...*/.addListener(new ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo image, bool synchronousCall) { /*...*/ }) as ImageStreamListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, here is some code only as an example

Code that broke:

```
var sunImage = new NetworkImage(incident.mobileSignature[0].uriFile,
          headers: AuthenticationService.getAuthHeaders());
sunImage.obtainKey(new ImageConfiguration()).then((val) {
    var load = sunImage.load(val);
    load.addListener((listener, err) async {
        ByteData data = await listener.image.toByteData(format:ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
        setState(() => this.signatureImage = data);
    });
  });
}
```

The code broke on line `load.addListener((listener, err) async { ....`

I solved creating an `ImageListener` function that does the same as my previous function with the `listener` variable. And then create an `ImageStreamListener` that receives this `ImageListener` as parameter. Note also that you can send as parameters `onError` and `onChunk` to the `ImageStreamListener`.

```
var sunImage = new NetworkImage(incident.mobileSignature[0].uriFile,
          headers: AuthenticationService.getAuthHeaders());
sunImage.obtainKey(new ImageConfiguration()).then((val) {
    var load = sunImage.load(val);
    ImageListener imageListener = (ImageInfo imageInfo, syncCall) async {
        ByteData data =
              await imageInfo.image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
          setState(() => this.signatureImage = data);
    };
    ImageStreamListener listenerStream = new ImageStreamListener(imageListener);
    load.addListener(listenerStream, onError: ...., onChunk: ......); // These last parameters are optional
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `animated_background` dependency in the `pubspec.yaml` file to the following:

```
animated_background:
    git: https://github.com/AndreBaltazar8/flutter_animated_background.git
```

Do a `flutter clean` afterwards and rebuild.

**Reason**: That happens because that dependency has actually been changed in the repo to match some of the framework changes related to the Image API, but not in the [pub.dev](https://pub.dev).

Answer (score 0):

Facing ImageStreamListener error in flutter printing plugin. I am using flutter 1.5.4 hotfix 2 version.

Use printing: 2.0.2  # fix it at this version to solve ImageStreamListener issue.

Hope it helps